# Javascript Countdown Timer with New Window

Tags: javascript, timer

I don't really know javascript, but I hacked together (i.e. found) the following code that does exactly what I want, EXCEPT, I want the window focus to end up on the one with the countdown timer.  In other words, I want to open the yahoo.com window, but not put it in focus.

Edit: I only really need this to work in IE11.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script language='JavaScript'>
var time = 10;
var page = "http://google.com";
function countDown(){
time--;
gett("container").innerHTML = time;
if(time == -1){
window.location = page;
}
}
function gett(id){
if(document.getElementById) return document.getElementById(id);
if(document.all) return document.all.id;
if(document.layers) return document.layers.id;
if(window.opera) return window.opera.id;
}
function init(){
if(gett('container')){
setInterval(countDown, 1000);
gett("container").innerHTML = time;
}
else{
setTimeout(init, 50);
}
}
document.onload = init();
window.open('http://www.yahoo.com');
</SCRIPT>
</head>
<body>
<H2>Google loading in <span id="container"></span> seconds...</H2>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script language='JavaScript'>
var time = 10;
var page = "http://google.com";
function countDown(){
time--;
gett("container").innerHTML = time;
if(time == -1){
window.open('http://www.yahoo.com',"_blank","toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=500, left=500, width=400, height=400");
}
}
function gett(id){
if(document.getElementById) return document.getElementById(id);
if(document.all) return document.all.id;
if(document.layers) return document.layers.id;
if(window.opera) return window.opera.id;
}
function init(){
if(gett('container')){
setInterval(countDown, 1000);
gett("container").innerHTML = time;
}
else{
setTimeout(init, 50);
}
}
document.onload = init();

</SCRIPT>
</head>
<body>
<H2>Google loading in <span id="container"></span> seconds...</H2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  No dice.  When the Yahoo window opens it is in focus.  Also I want the yahoo window to pop up immediately, not after the google timer is complete.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<h2>Google loading in <span id="counter">3</span> seconds...</h2>

<script>
document.onload = init() 
$elem = document.getElementById("counter");
var timer = $elem.innerHTML;
//timer = 30; //if you want start timer from javascript or change time inside counter
function init() {
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        timer = timer-1;
        $elem.innerHTML = timer;
        if(timer == 0) {  
           var popWindow = window.open("http://google.com", '_blank', 'location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes');
               popWindow.blur();
               window.focus();
           window.onblur = window.focus();
           clearInterval(interval);
        }
    },1000);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```